# ¿Cómo ejecutar un proceso en Delphi 10.3 al regresar a mi aplicación que se encontraba abierta (en segundo plano)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-tokyo, delphi-berlin, delphi-rio

Estoy trabajando con 2 aplicaciones las cuales comparten un archivo .txt el cual es es consultado por ambas, en la primera app dejo en el .txt el valor "5" y la segunda app al abrirse me muestra el valor "5" ya que lo consultó al INICIAR, el problema viene cuando la segunda app NO SE CIERRA y nos vamos a la primera app y le pongo el valor "3" al .txt y al entrar nuevamente a mi segunda app el valor que me muestra sigue siendo el "5" (YA QUE ESA APP NO SE CERRÓ), en que evento puedo consultar el .txt para que me muestre el valor "3" sin tener que cerrar mi aplicación? ósea que evento se ejecutar al reingresar a mi app sin haberla cerrado completamente?

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta quedaría mejor si nos muestras un poco de código, que deje ver cómo _muestras_ el valor o como procesas el archivo.  Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias opciones, pero como te han comentado ayudaría ver el código que estás utilizando.
Hay algunos componentes que puedes utilizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un **TTimer**, te permite ejecutar un determinado código cada X milisegundos; Si estás utilizando un formulario en tu proyecto, puedes usar este componente para consultar el valor del fichero cada x milisegundos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un **TApplicationEvents**, te permite acceder y programar algunos eventos genéricos a nivel de aplicación. Si tienes un formulario (al igual que con el anterior componente), puedes utilizarlo. POr ejemplo, el evento **OnIdle** te permitirá "releer" el fichero continuamente para consultar el nuevo valor.

Hay otras opciones, como revisar cambios en el fichero. Para ello puedes utilizar componentes de terceros o la API directamente, aunque esta opción parece un poco más compleja.
Si te interesa más información puedes buscar sobre la API **FindFirstChangeNotification**.